# How to make HTML element **not** rotatable on iPad?

Tags: javascript, html, ipad

I'm currently developing a little HTML5 Canvas/JavaScript based drawing application aimed for iPad. It runs in Safari. So far everything has worked great except for one thing.

If I rotate the device, my UI reorients itself. This is cool for most of the UI except for the canvas itself. Is there some way to force the canvas **not** to be rotated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about setting up orientation specific CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/landscape.css" media="all and (orientation:landscape)">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/portrait.css" media="all and (orientation:portrait)">
```

and putting:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg)
```

in one of the two orientations to counteract the automatic rotation?

Comment: Cool idea. Gotta try something along this. I think I'll have to transform my Canvas coords somehow in this case. Just some extra math for me to handle. :)

Comment: if you do it right you can keep the canvas coordinates the same - the style values and on-screen values don't have to be consistent.

Comment: Ok. I'll keep this question open for a while (12 hours or so?) and accept yours in case nothing else shows up. Thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: in any event the worse you'll have to do is apply a uniform scaling transormation to your canvas's context.  You can then keep your pixel coordinates the same in either orientation.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone wonders how to implement Alnitak's answer in practice, here you go:

CSS:

```
@media all and (orientation:portrait) {
    #myCanvas {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg)
    }    
}
```

Alternatively you can use separate CSS files if you want to.

In order to get the canvas coordinate system in sync with this you can use something along this:

```
ctx.save();

...

if(window.orientation == 0 || window.orientation == 180) {
    ctx.translate(canvasWidth, 0);
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 2);
}

...

ctx.restore();
```

There might be some other ways to achieve the same result but this seemed to work ok for me. Note that it's a good idea to save/restore context state so you don't mess it up on rotate.